# Need help with passing variables between two functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

This should be an easy question for many of you!

Background:
I am having difficulty passing a variable between two functions in javascript using the jQuery library.

Below is a script I am working on that dynamically loads content based on the index of workSnippet. The top function works. The second function does not work. No alert is given, as portfolioCount variable does not seem to exist.

My Question:
How do I pass the variable between the two functions so that when 'next' is clicked, I can alert portfolioCount?

Thanks

```
// set global variable 
var portfolioCount = 0;

// begin on document ready
       $(document).ready(function() {
 // Return the value of the index of workSnippet when clicked and load related content

$(".workSnippet").click(function () {

    //set variable portfolioCount based on index

    var portfolioCount = $(".workSnippet").index(this);

    //load content based on portfolioCount

    $('#work #cycle' + portfolioCount).load("ajax-content/ajax-content.php #portfolioImage" + portfolioCount);

    // when loaded, run animation functions 

    $("#work").ajaxComplete(function(){

        setTimeout(invokeMultipleCycle, 200);

        showWork();
        $('#work').cycle(portfolioCount);
        $('#blurbs').cycle(portfolioCount);

        return portfolioCount;
    });

});

// return cycle value when 'next' is clicked

$('#next').click(function () {

    alert(portfolioCount);
});

});
```

Comment: If you `alert(portfolioCount)` right after assigning it in the click handler, what number is alerted?  Your problem may lie there, and not in your variable scoping.

Comment: (Also, right here, your global variable is never referenced.  Are you sure you understand JavaScript closure rules?)

Comment: Nevermind; I misread the code.  I didn't notice the code scrolled to reveal the `$('#next').click` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the global thus, outside the functions:

```
var portfolioCount=0;
```

Then remove the 'var' keyword from this line:

```
var portfolioCount = $(".workSnippet").index(this);
```

/sim

Comment: This was the problem, I never knew this! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `portfolioCount` as a global variable.

Alternatively

```
  $('#next').click(function () {
        var item = $(".workSnippet");
        var portfolioCount=$(".workSnippet").index(item);
        alert(portfolioCount);
    });
```

Comment: I tried declaring portfolioCount as global by typing var portfolioCount = 0; at the top of the script before all functions but it will always give '0' in the alert (when next is clicked). I tried your alternative but it does not work as the index catches the click, not the element.

Answer (score 0):

you can save it in a global javascript variable

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring portfolioCount twice. the portfolioCount inside of the $('.worksnippet').click() callback is an entirely different variable inside of said callback's scope. try removing the 'var' keyword from inside the click callback's assignment of portfolioCount and it should use the global one.